# code first two Foreign Keys from same table

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

Using Entity Framework Core (5.0.17) code first I'm having trouble implementing a class that has two references to another class.

this is my structure:

```
public class Beneficio
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int ComercioBeneficioId { get; set; }
    public int ComercioOtorgadorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ComercioBeneficioId")]
    public Comercio ComercioBeneficio { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ComercioOtorgadorId")]
    public Comercio ComercioOtorgador { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Comercio
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

The Required attributes on the location references makes it impossible to update the table on the database . This is the error message I get:

> Introducing `FOREIGN KEY` constraint '`FK_Races_Locations_StartLocationId`' on table '`Races`' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>
> Specify `ON DELETE NO ACTION` or `ON UPDATE NO ACTION`, or modify other `FOREIGN KEY` constraints.
>
> Could not create constraint or index.

Comment: The name of the `FK_Races_Locations_StartLocationId` constraint does not correspond to _any_ of your posted C#.

Comment: `public int Id { get; set; }` <-- "`Id`" is a bad choice for a column-name, especially when used in multiple tables, because when you have any kind of non-trivial query (like when you use a `JOIN` or derived-table or CTE) you'll have many columns, all named `Id` you won't know what what the source table was without needing to look it up or be forced to alias it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The model has multiple cascade path :

```
Beneficio -> ComercioBeneficio
          -> ComercioOtorgador
```

And SQL Sever don't allow this. To understand, see this data :

```
BeneficioA -> (Beneficio) ComercioA
           -> (Otorgador) ComercioA
```

In the `BeneficioA`, the Beneficio and the Otorgador is the same `ComercioA`. Then when `BeneficioA` is removed, by cascade `ComercioA` is removed two times.

But this seems legit, just need to `ComercioA` one time. Other DBMS like MySQL manage this. Then why not SQL Server?

I don't know and found no official information about this. Just found this :

> [SQL Server - Why can't we have multiple cascade paths?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100493/why-cant-we-have-multiple-cascade-paths)
>
> ...so instead of fixing it, the implementation avoids it by preventing the definition of duplicate cascade paths. It's clearly a short-cut...

SQL Server has this constraint and we need to live with. A solution is to disable the delete cascade behavior by setting the foreign key and navigation property nullable :

```cs
public class Beneficio
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ComercioBeneficioId { get; set; }
    public int? ComercioOtorgadorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ComercioBeneficioId")]
    public Comercio? ComercioBeneficio { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ComercioOtorgadorId")]
    public Comercio? ComercioOtorgador { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: _"A solution is to disable the delete cascade behavior by setting the foreign key and navigation property nullable"_ - ...but doing that changes the nature of the FK relationship and may be incorrect (w.r.t. the OP's requirements). You can still have required, `NOT NULL` FKs, by using `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` and managing deletes via explicit commands (and in a `TRANSACTION`). I've never been a fan of cascading updates/deletes (nor triggers) because they make a database's state less predictable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fluent api to configure the relationship

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Comercio>()
       .HasMany<Beneficio>()
       .WithOne(g => g.ComercioBeneficio)
       .HasForeignKey(j => j.ComercioBeneficioId).OnDelete(DeleteBehabiour.SetNull);
 }
```

Do this on both properties. And as per mentioned @vernou, you need to make the foreign key nullable so that the relationship is optional